# How to iteratively plot auto.arima forecasts using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I have the following data:

```
df

   repo revrepo bankrate  CRR Callrate
1  9.00    6.75      7.0 8.00     7.49
2  8.75    6.50      7.0 7.50     8.03
3  8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.24
4  8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.19
5  8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     6.94
6  8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.30
7  8.50    6.50      6.5 7.50     7.40
8  8.50    6.50      6.5 5.75     6.97
9  8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     7.08
10 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     6.63
11 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     6.73
12 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.97
13 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.58
14 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.90
15 8.00    5.75      6.5 5.00     6.04
```

I am iteratively plotting the ts as below:

```
y=df
colnames <- dimnames(y)[[2]]

(plots<-lapply(df,function(x) autoplot(fit<-forecast(auto.arima(ts(x,start=c(2001,4),end = c(2002,6),frequency = 12))))+labs(x = 'Time', y = paste(colnames[i])) + ggtitle(paste(colnames[i],'over Time'))+  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
yaztheme::theme_yaz() ))
```

I am not getting the correct title of the plots.Showing one of plots for reference:

[image]

Is there a better method to do the iterative timeseries forecasting and plotting of the forecasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the corresponding column names, loop through the sequence of columns

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(df),function(i) {
autoplot(fit<-forecast(auto.arima(ts(df[[i]],start=c(2001,4),
                end = c(2002,6),frequency = 12))))+
         labs(x = 'Time', y = paste(colnames[i])) +
         ggtitle(paste(colnames[i],'over Time'))+ 
         theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  } 
)

lst[[5]]
```

[image]

---

Or the same with a `for` loop

```
lst <- vector('list', length(df))
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  lst[[i]] <- autoplot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(df[[i]],
             start=c(2001,4),end = c(2002,6),frequency = 12))))+
           labs(x = 'Time', y = paste(colnames[i])) +
           gtitle(paste(colnames[i],'over Time'))+ 
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

}
```

Comment: fantastic btw can you correct ggtitle synatx (incorrectly written as gtitle)